# My image won't show but the resolution of my image is applied

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm learning the tkinter module and I got a problem. I did a fonction to show an image from my folder but my image won't show up but the resolution of the window is the same as my image. Anybody have a solution ?

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

root = Tk()

def my_image(img, row, column) :
    pic = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("C:/Users/Mark/Downloads/test/" + img))
    my_img = Label(image=pic)
    return my_img.grid(row=row, column=column)

# Create image
image1 = my_image("luigi_icon.png", 0, 1)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: `pic` is a temporary variable and will disappear when `my_image` return. Should save it somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

This problem was many times on Stackoverflow.

There is `bug` in `PhotoImage` which removes image from memory when it is assigned to local variable. You have to assign it to global variable or to some object

Common solution is to assign `pic` to `label` which displays it.

```
my_img.pic = pic
```

See `Note` at the end of page [PhotoImage](https://web.archive.org/web/20201112023229/http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/photoimage.htm)
(it is archived version on `Wayback Machine` because original version was removed)

---

BTW:

You have other problem. `grid()` gives `None`. You should return `my_img` if you want to access label later (ie. to replace image).

Currently original `tk.PhotoImage` can work with `png` so you don't need `PIL`. But if you want to work with some less popular image format then you may need `pillow`.

---

```
import os
#from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk  # PEP8: `import *` is not preferred
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

# --- functions ---

def my_image(img, row, column) :
    fullpath = os.path.join("C:/Users/Mark/Downloads/test/", img)

    #pic = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(fullpath))
    # or
    #pic =  ImageTk.PhotoImage(file=fullpath)
    # or even without `PIL/pillow` for `png`
    pic = tk.PhotoImage(file=fullpath)

    my_img = tk.Label(image=pic)
    my_img.grid(row=row, column=column)

    my_img.pic = pic  # solution for bug in `PhotoImage`

    return my_img

# --- main ---

root = tk.Tk()

image1 = my_image("luigi_icon.png", 0, 1)

root.mainloop()
```